# Откуда в 24 строке в componentWillReceiveProps берется ymaps?

Tags: reactjs, yandex-maps-jsapi

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { updateCenter, updateRoute } from '../actions'
import { YMaps, Map } from 'react-yandex-maps'

const mapState = {  center: [55.751574, 37.573856],
    zoom: 14,
    controls: ['zoomControl'] };

class MapContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.map = null;
        this.state={ 
            items: this.props.routeList,
            center: []
        };
    }    
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        if(nextProps.routeList !== this.props.routeList){
            this.map.geoObjects.removeAll();                      
            this.setState({items: nextProps.routeList}, () => {
                **this.onApiAvailable(ymaps);**
            });
        }
    }
    onApiAvailable = (ymaps) => {   
        if (this.state.items && this.state.items.length > 0){
            this.state.items.forEach((item)=>{
                let text = item.text;                
                ymaps.geocode(item.coord).then((res)=>{
                    let firstGeoObject = res.geoObjects.get(0);
                    // получаем адрес по координате метки
                    let address = firstGeoObject.getAddressLine();
                    let newPlacemark = new window.ymaps.Placemark(item.coord, {
                        hintContent: text,
                        balloonContent: `${text} <br/> ${address}`
                    }, {
                        iconLayout: 'default#image',
                        draggable: true
                    });
                    // добавляем метку на карту
                    this.map.geoObjects.add(newPlacemark);
                    // обновляем координаты метки в state после перетаскивания
                    newPlacemark.events.add('dragend', (e) => {
                        let coords = e.get('target').geometry.getCoordinates();
                        this.props.updateRoute(item.id, coords);
                    });
                });                
            });
            // получаем координаты меток и соединяем прямой линией
            let routePoints = this.props.routeList.map((point)=> point.coord);
            this.map.geoObjects.add(new ymaps.Polyline(routePoints, {}, {strokeWidth: 3}));            
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <YMaps onApiAvaliable={(ymaps) => this.onApiAvailable(ymaps)}>
                <Map
                    state={mapState}
                    instanceRef={(ref) => {
                        this.map = ref;
                        const center = this.map.getCenter();
                        this.setState({center: center}, ()=> this.props.updateCenter(this.state.center));
                    }}
                    width='100%'
                    onBoundsChange={()=> {
                        const center = this.map.getCenter();
                        this.setState({center: center}, ()=> this.props.updateCenter(this.state.center));
                    }}
                >
                </Map>
            </YMaps>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps (state) {
    return {
        routeList: state.routeList
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return bindActionCreators({ updateCenter, updateRoute }, dispatch)
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(MapContainer);
```

Comment: Предлагаете вручную отсчитывать 26 строк?

Comment: А с чего Вы взяли что он там берется?

Comment: передается в this.onApiAvailable же.

Comment: Я вижу, но с чего Вы решили что это правильный код?